# LUN numbers not ordered when deployed through terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-azure, azureportal

I'm able to successfully deploying 5 data disks using terraform on Azure but when i check in portal these data disks are not ordered randomly like ( lun3, lun1, lun0, lun2, lun4) but when i deploy the same using ARM template they are updated in an order.

below is my code for attaching disks

```
resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "disk" {
  for_each             = toset([for index in local.map : j.index])
  name                 = ...
  location             = ...
  resource_group_name  = ...
  storage_account_type = ...
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = ..
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "disk_attach" {
  for_each           = toset([for index in local.map : j.index])
  lun                = 0..n
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.disk[each.key].id
  virtual_machine_id = ...
  caching            = "None"
}
```

`terraform plan` is generating resource in a sequential order but once the deployment is done the order in which they are populated in azure portal is random. I checked in documentation [virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment) & [managed_disk](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/managed_disk) but they are no flags/options/properties for such sequential ordering.

I have also checked `az disk list` but could not get much info to solve this.

[image]

**Is there any way to make sure terraform generates & attaches data disks sequentially similar to how ARM template is doing i.e., in the order of LUN number ?**

Comment: solved the issue by removing managed_disk & disk_attach and added a dynamic tag for storage_disk

Answer (score 1):

Here are two suggestions:

1. You may consider deploying ARM Templates with Terraform. Read [this blog](https://samcogan.com/deploying-arm-templates-with-terraform/) for more details.
2. Try to create the data disk with `count` or `for_each` referring to examples in [this blog](https://www.nealshah.dev/posts/2020/05/terraform-for-azure-deploying-multiple-vms-with-multiple-managed-disks/).

For example:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "managed_disk_attach" {
  count              = length(var.instances) * var.nb_disks_per_instance
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.managed_disk.*.id[count.index]
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm.*.id[ceil((count.index + 1) * 1.0 / var.nb_disks_per_instance) - 1]
  lun                = count.index + 10
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}
```

or use `for_each`, you can use

```
    locals {
      vm_datadiskdisk_count_map = { for k in toset(var.instances) : k => var.nb_disks_per_instance }
      luns                      = { for k in local.datadisk_lun_map : k.datadisk_name => k.lun }
      datadisk_lun_map = flatten([
        for vm_name, count in local.vm_datadiskdisk_count_map : [
          for i in range(count) : {
            datadisk_name = format("datadisk_%s_disk%02d", vm_name, i)
            lun           = i
          }
        ]
      ])
    }



resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "managed_disk" {
  for_each             = toset([for j in local.datadisk_lun_map : j.datadisk_name])
  name                 = each.key
  location             = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = 10
  tags                 = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "managed_disk_attach" {
  for_each           = toset([for j in local.datadisk_lun_map : j.datadisk_name])
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.managed_disk[each.key].id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.vm[element(split("_", each.key), 1)].id
  lun                = lookup(local.luns, each.key)
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}
```